# Feedly API - How to get feed content

Tags: api, rss, feedly

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get content (articles) from a feed using Feedly API. The [documentation](https://developer.feedly.com/v3/feeds/) says I should do

> GET /v3/feeds/:feedId

and `feedId`s seem to be in form of 
`feedId: "feed/http://www.theverge.com/rss/full.xml"`

However, doing a call in the forms below fail with different errors.

> cloud.feedly.com/v3/feeds/feed/http://www.theverge.com/rss/full.xml
>   cloud.feedly.com/v3/feed/http://www.theverge.com/rss/full.xml
>   cloud.feedly.com/v3/feeds/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Frss%2Ffull.xml
>   cloud.feedly.com/v3/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Frss%2Ffull.xml

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get the content of a stream, you need to use the [streams](https://developer.feedly.com/v3/streams/#get-the-content-of-a-stream) API. E.g. `GET https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=feed/http://www.theverge.com/rss/full.xml`.

Regarding the feeds API, the reason you're getting errors is because you need to URL-encode the feedId (it can contain special characters like "?" or "&"). For example: `GET https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/feeds/feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Frss%2Ffull.xml`.

Hope this helps.